# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute on insert from form

Tags: python-3.x, insert, flask-pymongo

I am trying to add form data to mongodb using flask-pymongo insert. I get the following error, and I cant see what I am doing wrong

I've tried following tutorials on youtube but while my code seems similar i still get error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute".

```
@users.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    print("your in the user route login")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("you are in post route")
        if request.form['username'] and request.form['password'] == "":
            print("no data was collected")
        else:
            users_login = mongo.db.fred
            users_login.insert({'user': request.form['username'],\ 
            'password': request.form['password']})
            print("submitted to db")

            return render_template('login.html')
        return render_template('login.html')
```

was hoping form fields collected with request.form would be posted to db but just get error

Comment: can you give me a full code in gist ?

https://gist.github.com/

Comment: what do you need everything, will take a while to work out git

Comment: do you you just need __init__.py and route, plus settings.py or anything else, not sure what you need in order to help?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dannychr9/699a8b39fde29bd03a0026e9e24b1def

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by starting overagain and by using user_collection = mongo.db.user which is the targeted collection.  so does this mean you cant specify a variable for mongo.db.user, and you need to use user_collection ?  T